# Can you win a two player Uno game by playing a skip card then your final card?

Tags: uno

My boyfriend and I are playing a game of two player Uno.

It’s my turn, and I have a red Skip card and a red 9. The color of the pile is currently red. If I place down my Skip card, skipping his turn, then say Uno and put down my red 9, do I win?

I’ve heard of this being called “Uno out”, but I need to clarify since he doesn’t believe me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a good way to win. Since you played a skip card in a two player game it is your turn again letting you play your final card and win the game. It should be noted that he would still have time to say uno if he could say it before you did or you played your final card.